# JDBC - The result set has no current row error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm having the following error whenever I run my program.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has
>   no current row.

The program is supposed to print off user selected data from my MySQL database. I run the SQL code as a query with no issues so I'm not sure why it has an issue in my Java program.

```
// Use the JDBC driver  
import java.sql.*;  
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SQLTest {  

        public static void main(String[] args) {  

            String numOfEmployees, username, password, selectSQL, results;
            int variableSelection;

            //Creates scanner object and asks for username and password.
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Username: ");
            username = input.next();
            System.out.println("Password: ");
            password = input.next();

            //Logs into MySQL database with given username and password.
            String connectionString =  
                "jdbc:sqlserver://steffentest.database.windows.net:1433;"  
                + "database=testdb;"  
                + "user=" +username+ "@steffentest;"  
                + "password="+password+";"  
                + "encrypt=true;"  
                + "trustServerCertificate=false;"  
                + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"  
                + "loginTimeout=30;";  




            // Declare the JDBC objects.  
            Connection connection = null;  
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;


            try {  
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString); 


                System.out.println("Successfully logged in...\n");

                System.out.println("Number of employees to view: ");
                numOfEmployees = input.next();

                System.out.println("What information would you like to see?");
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                System.out.println("1) Company Name");
                System.out.println("2) Email Address");
                System.out.println("3) Phone Number");
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                variableSelection = input.nextInt();

                switch (variableSelection)
                {
                case 1: 
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    selectSQL = "SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + "Title, FirstName, LastName, CompanyName from SalesLT.Customer";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
                    results = "Name: " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3) + "\nCompany: " + resultSet.getString(4) + "\n";
                    System.out.println("");
                    while (resultSet.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(results);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    selectSQL = "SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + "Title, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress from SalesLT.Customer";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
                    results = "Name: " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3) + "\nEmail Address: " + resultSet.getString(4) + "\n";
                    System.out.println("");
                    while (resultSet.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(results);

                    }
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    selectSQL = "SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + "Title, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber from SalesLT.Customer";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
                    results = "Name: " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3) + "\nPhone Number: " + resultSet.getString(4) + "\n";
                    System.out.println("");
                    while (resultSet.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(results);

                    }
                    break;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number 1-3.");
                    break;
                }   
            }  
            catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            finally {  
                if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch(Exception e) {} 
                if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                input.close();
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean that the result set returned no registration. This means that the set of records is not set to the row you want to read.

The first time you load the set of records is not positioned for any row. So `rs.next()` will position the result set of the first row (ie, make the first row of the current row), so you can read some data from that row. The result set must have a current row to read some data from it.

```
System.out.println("");
while (resultSet.next())
{
 results = "Name: " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3) + "\nCompany: " + resultSet.getString(4) + "\n";
                System.out.println(results);
}
```

careful with spaces when concatenating the query apparently has no space numOfEmployees title

```
"SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + " Title,... // space
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid SQL

Try changing these type of lines so that have correct spaces

e.g.

```
"SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + "Title,
```

to

```
"SELECT TOP " + numOfEmployees + " Title,
```

Also it would be safer to test whether you have a valid resultSet using

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first()